# How can I add 2 or more URL in one event in FullCalendar control using jquery?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have added an event like "Total Records 2/3". I need 2 URL for this event. When I click on "2" it will redirect to "www.URL1.com" and when I click on "3" it will redirect to "www.URL2.com".

Is there any possibility to link 2 different URL in 1 event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. One way is to override the URL and instead open a modal window that presents them with the URL choices. You would need to have a custom field in your feed source that has the 2nd URL value.

**[View example](http://mikesmithdev.com/blog/jquery-full-calendar-with-ui-modal-dialog/)**

It would be easy enough to modify this example to present them with two URL choices. Hope that helps.